# Handling ajax-request in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have a very basic leaflet map using `leaflet-panel-layers` to create a pretty layer control. I have two functions to create my layers and overlays. My data is in external geoJSON-Files what seems to be my problem as leaflet does not offer anything to get an external geoJSON. I also use `proj4leaflet` library to use the projection given in my json. 
So google told me to use ajax about which I unfortunately don't know anything. I copy-pasted something like this:

```
function getOverlays(){
    var url = 'myServerUrl';
    overlays = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
        success: function(response) {
            overlays.push({
                name: "Something",
                layer: L.Proj.geoJson(response, {
                ...
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return overlays;
}
```

my map is built like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: layers[0].layer
});
var layers = getBaseLayers();
var overlays = getOverlays();
var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(layers,overlays);
map.addControl(panelLayers);
```

This actually works fine if I want to add the layers to the map directly. But in my case the asynchronous request seems to be ready **after** my layer switcher is added to my map so the layers don't appear there.
Is there any way to solve this simply without diving into callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your control after request has finished. This can be done with a callback function:

```
function getOverlays(callback){
    var url = 'myServerUrl';
    overlays = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
        success: function(response) {
            overlays.push({
                name: "Something",
                layer: L.Proj.geoJson(response, {
                ...
                }
            });
            callback(overlays)
        }
    });
    return overlays;
}

var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: layers[0].layer
});
var layers = getBaseLayers();
getOverlays(function(overlays){
    var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(layers,overlays);
    map.addControl(panelLayers);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine for one layer - what if i have a larger number of layers, let's say in a for loop. How could I initialize the map after the **last** layer finished?

Comment: I should better have a look at your code. Anyway, do it the same way - create a flag that indicates that all layers a loaded (for example if your loop finished) and call the callback if your flag becomes `true`