# Leaflet Overlay Layers Control Menu with JQuery ajax Call (GeoServer WFS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, leaflet, layer

I can setup a LeafletJS map having multiple (overlay) layers and to manage their visibility with a control menu when using basic GeoJSON files, exactly like the doc example : http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/.

This works fine :

```
  var geojson_layer1 = L.geoJson.ajax("layer1.geojson", {style: style, onEachFeature:onEachFeature});
  var geojson_layer2 = L.geoJson.ajax("layer2.geojson", {style: style, onEachFeature:onEachFeature});
  ...
  geojson_layer1.addTo(map);
  geojson_layer2.addTo(map);
  ...
  var baseMaps = {
       "MyMap": map
   };

   var overlayMaps = {
     "Layer1": Layer1,
     "Layer2": Layer2
  };

  ...

  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

---

Now I try to do the same (still basemap + overlay layers with control) but with data coming from a GeoServer (WMS/WFS). For this I use JQuery ajax call, eg :

```
var xyz_Parameters = {
          service: 'WFS',
          version: '1.0.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
          typeName: 'myworkspace:xyz',
          maxFeatures: '50',
          outputFormat: 'application/json',
};

var parameters_xyz = L.Util.extend(xyz_Parameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters_xyz);
console.log(URL);

$.ajax({ url: URL, success: function (data) {
      var geojson_layer_1 = new L.geoJson(data, {style: style, onEachFeature:doNothing});
      geojson_layer_1.addTo(map);
  }
});
```

This works fine too BUT I'm unable to manage the layers visibility through menu as variable (geojson_layer_1 here) is not seen globally.

Actually my problem comes with the async/callback (normal) behavior. I'd like to know how to manager a layer object with callback.
I've seen lot of things on the web (eg : [Handling ajax-request in leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340111/handling-ajax-request-in-leaflet-map#31340970)) but either it is not exactly what I want or I wasn't able to make them work.

Does anyone would have a (more) **complete** example ?

Thanks.
Tom